# Назначение toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть 2 вида боковых стрелок - закрытая (направленная вправо - в состоянии закрытого подменю - `.arrow_01_R`) и открытая (направленная вниз - в состоянии открытого подменю - `.arrow_01_B`). Каким образом можно по щелчку поменять ориентацию стрелки с использованием оператора toggleClass

```js
let elemsofarrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_01_R, .arrow_01_B');

for (let i = 0; i < elemsofarrows.length; i++) {
  elemsofarrows[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      elemsofarrows[i].classList.toggleClass('.arrow_01_R');
      /*elemsofarrows[i].classList.toggleClass('.arrow_01_B');*/
    }
  }
```

Каким образом можно назначить противоположным классу `.arrow_01_B` класс `.arrow_01_R`?

Answer (score 1):

То, что вам нужно, можно сделать проще - назначить классу .arrow направленную вправо стрелку, а .arrow.active - направленную вниз. И потом так:

```js
let elemsofarrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

for (let i = 0; i < elemsofarrows.length; i++) {
  elemsofarrows[i].classList.toggleClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы по дефолту для стрелки назначил бы в CSS для класса (например `.menu`) одну картинку, а для `.menu.open` - вторую. И тогда в *JS* достаточно было бы оперировать переключением класса `open`